# Line segments with text in the middle in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Another exam, another image. I am trying to create the following image in TikZ

[image: Exam curtains]

Now. I am looking for some feedback on my code. I am trying to learn TikZ as fast as I can, but still I feel I am doing things in an overly complicated or hugely inefficient way.

My main problem is finding the best way to create the line segments on the left. How do I do this? Breaking them up and placing text in between just is meh.

My attempt is below. Please pay little attention to it as it really sucks.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
\tkzDefPoint(-0.1,0){P}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(1.2,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0.8){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,1.6){C}
\tkzDefPoint(1.2,0){G}
\tkzDefPoint(1.2,.83){U}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center B angle 110](C) \tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center O angle  35](G) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzDefMidPoint(B,E) \tkzGetPoint{M1}
\tkzDefMidPoint(C,E) \tkzGetPoint{M2}
\tkzMarkAngle[thick,scale=0.5,fill=black!20!white](A,O,E)
\tkzMarkAngle[thick,scale=0.4,fill=black!20!white](E,B,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[thick](P,A)
\draw[thick](-0.6,0)--(-0.4,0);\draw[thick](-0.6,1.6)--(-0.4,1.6);
\draw[thick](-0.1,0.8)--(-0.3,0.8);\draw[thick](-0.1,1.6)--(-0.3,1.6);
\draw[thick](-0.2,1.6)--(-0.2,1.3);\draw[thick](-0.2,0.8)--(-0.2,1.1);
\draw[thick](-0.5,0.0)--(-0.5,0.6);\draw[thick](-0.5,0.8)--(-0.5,1.6);
\tkzDrawSegment[ultra thick,Goldenrod,dashed](O,U)
\tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick](O,C B,E)
\tkzDrawSegment[ultra thick,Magenta](C,E)
\tkzLabelPoint[left=-.55](-0.2,1.2){$0.8$ m} ;
\tkzLabelPoint[left=-.65](-0.5,0.7){$\stackrel{\text{\large Vindu}}{1.6     \text{m}}$} ;
\tkzLabelPoint[above=0.2](M1){Arm} ;
\tkzLabelPoint[below left](M1){$0.8$m} ;
\tkzLabelPoint[above=0.2,right, Magenta](M2){$\mathit{\mathbf{L}}$} ;
\tkzLabelPoint[above=1,Magenta](M2){\bfseries Markiseduk} ;
\tkzLabelPoint[below=1.75,left,Goldenrod](E){\bfseries Solstr\aa le} ;
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.3](A,O,E){$u$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.225](E,B,C){$v$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My result...

[image: Here is my attemp to TikZ]

Comment: Aren't you afraid your students might read this? Nice exam preparation! ;-)

Comment: It`s an old exam, I am just clening them up and adding solutions for them! ^^

Comment: I have the feeling that this would be a lot simpler in plain TikZ. For example, the yellow line could be drawn along with the label with a simple command like `\draw[ultra thick,Goldenrod,dashed] (O) -- (U) node[midway,below right] {\bfseries Solstr\aa le};`.

Comment: It's a lot simpler if you have studied `Tikz` but for someone who does not to know all about `tikz' but who wants to draw only geometric pictures, perhaps it's a fine way. With this package, I hope that the user tries to study `tikz`because a lot of "styles"  (options) are the same. It will be easy to work with tikz after that. Its also easy to pass from `pst-eucl` to `tkz-euclide`without to know all the pgfmanual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `tkz-euclide` but I remark a bug because I need to use `pos=0.4` to place the label vertically (??)

version 2 with option `|-|``

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
\tkzDefPoint(-0.1,0){P}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(1.2,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0.8){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,1.6){C}
\tkzDefPoint(1.2,0){G}
\tkzDefPoint(1.2,.83){U}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center B angle 110](C) \tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center O angle  35](G) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[B](-0.2,0){B'} 
\tkzDefShiftPoint[C](-0.2,0){C'} 
\tkzDefShiftPoint[O](-0.6,0){O''} 
\tkzDefShiftPoint[C](-0.6,0){C''} 

\tkzMarkAngle[thick,scale=0.5,fill=black!20!white](A,O,E)
\tkzMarkAngle[thick,scale=0.4,fill=black!20!white](E,B,C)
\tkzDrawSegment[thick](P,A)
\tkzDrawSegment[ultra thick,Goldenrod,dashed](O,U)
\tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick](O,C B,E)
\tkzDrawSegment[ultra thick,Magenta](C,E)     
\tkzDrawSegments[|-|](B',C' O'',C'') 

\tkzLabelSegment[above=0.2](B,E){Arm} 
\tkzLabelSegment[below left](B,E){$0.8$m} 
\tkzLabelSegment[above=0.2,right, Magenta](C,E){$\mathit{\mathbf{L}}$} 
\tkzLabelSegment[above=1,Magenta](C,E){\bfseries Markiseduk}  
\tkzLabelSegment[pos=.4,fill=white,inner sep=10pt](B',C'){$0.8$ m}
\tkzLabelSegment[pos=.4,fill=white,inner sep=10pt,align=center](O'',C''){\large Vindu\\$1.6$ m} 
\tkzLabelPoint[below=1.75,left,Goldenrod](E){\bfseries Solstr\aa le} 
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.3](A,O,E){$u$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.225](E,B,C){$v$}  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found the bug in \tkzLabelSegment`. I need to remove `above` in the code below `\def\tkz@LabelSegment[#1](#2,#3)#4{%
\begingroup    
\path  (#2) to node[above,#1]{#4} (#3) ;  
\endgroup 
}`

Answer (score 7):

Another way to break the line is to draw it *after* the node and make it go via the node.  When you do that, then TikZ breaks the line to "hop" over the node.  As a simple example:

```
\node (a) at (0,0) {a};
\draw (-3,0) -- (a) -- (3,0);
```

will produce:

```
---- a ----
```

(okay, it'll look a bit nice than that!)

Comment: I'm trying to find something shorter (same idea occurred). Do you reckon anything can be done with a decoration? Probably overkill! Obviously this would entail a lot more code somewhere. I guess this will be the shortest in practical terms.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt I guess that by "shorter" you would want it all done in a single command.  You still need the node to be *actually* placed first so that the path knows where to break itself, but as it's placed at a certain location on the path then it should be possible.  Not sure how much hacking would be involved, though.  Possibly decorations, or pre/post actions.  I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would have done it, but it is definitely a matter of taste. You can also play around with the angle -105 to get different outputs for your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0cm,outer sep=0cm},scale=5]
\draw[thick]  (0,0) node (O) {} --  (0,0.8cm) node(M) {} -- (0,1.6cm) node (T) {} (0,0.8cm) -- ($(M)!1!-105:(T)$) node (tip){}; 
\draw (-2mm,0) -- node (justanode) {} (1.2cm,0);
\draw[magenta] (T) --node[near start,above right=2mm] {{\bfseries Markiseduk}} node[midway,above right=1mm] {L} (tip);
\draw[yellow!80!black,densely dashed] (O) -- node[midway,below right=1mm] {{\bfseries Solstr\aa le}} ($(O)!1.1!(tip)$);
\draw[|-|] ($(T) + (-2mm,0)$) -- node[fill=white,inner sep=1mm,midway] {0.8 m}($(M) + (-2mm,0)$);
\draw[|-|] ($(T) + (-4mm,0)$) -- node[fill=white,inner sep=1mm,text width=1cm,midway] {Vindu 1.6 m}($(O) + (-4mm,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A very crude way of making those lines with labels is with the following macro

```
\newcommand{\midlabelline}[3]{
   \node (midlabel) at ($ (#1)!.5!(#2) $) {#3};
   \draw[|-,thick] (#1) --  (midlabel);
   \draw[-|,thick] (midlabel) -- (#2);
}
```

which requires the `calc` library, i.e. `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`. This can obviously be improved, but it will do what you want with a command like:

```
\midlabelline{-20,80}{-20,160}{0.8\,m}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the node with a white background. The line you are trying to create would be generated by:

```
\tikz\path[draw] (0,0) -- ++(1,0) ++(-0.5,0) -- ++(0,-5) node[pos=0.5,fill=white] {Vindu} ++(.5,0) -- ++(-1,0);
```

To get it to two lines, you need to add text alignment and width. If you want the white space to be a little greater, increase the `inner sep` with `inner sep=6pt`, for instance, on the node.

Comment: Or `\tikz \draw[|-|] (0,0) to node [fill=white]{text} (0,5) ;` by default you have `pos=.5`