# Draw dimension of a line as a decoration in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, dimensions, technical-drawing

Is it possible to define in TikZ a new decoration or something like that, such that it is possible to write something like:

```
\draw[dim={text,above}] (A) -- (B);
\draw[dim={text,below}] (C) -- (D);
```

or even better

```
\draw (A) dim[text,above] (B);
\draw (C) dim[text,below] (C);
```

to get something like this:

[image: dim]

It's important that the text is sloped.

If possible I would prefer the second syntax, because then I could easily combine such path's:

```
\draw (A) dim[text,above] (B) -- (C) -- (D) dim[text] (E) dim[text,below] (F) -- circle;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dimensioning of a technical drawing in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the object I want is slightly different, because I want a special syntax and because I want to have the label sloped

Comment: I agree that it isn't a duplicate, just a related question. Having a `dim` option might be possible, but having a `dim` path command is not possible (as long you don't rewrite TikZ internal path parser).

Comment: You can also do this via defining a new decoration with `|-|` type of arrows. See this question ["Line segments with text in the middle in TikZ"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36257/line-segments-with-text-in-the-middle-in-tikz/36262#36262) and answers for different solutions.

Comment: @percusse But how to get the double lines for my case?

Comment: @user4011 I'm really sorry. I am caught up in some detail, I can't work on it now. But @Altermundus' answer looks quite nice. What I meant is to combine `latex-latex` and `|-|` arrows, then put it in a decoration alas Altermundus does. The arrow combination is given in Section 74.3 in the manual v.2.10

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Update**

The result looks fine but perhaps the code can be improved.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.markings,decorations.text}

\begin{document}
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/.cd,
      distance/.initial=10pt
}  

\pgfdeclaredecoration{add dim}{final}{
\state{final}{% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dist}{5pt*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/distance}/abs(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/distance})} 
          \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}             
          \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2*\dist}}   
          \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{0pt}} 
          \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{(\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{2*\dist}}
           \pgfusepath{stroke} 
          \pgfsetdash{{0.1cm}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}}{0cm}     
          \pgfsetarrowsstart{latex}
          \pgfsetarrowsend{latex}  
          \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\dist}}
          \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{\dist}} 
          \pgfusepath{stroke} 
          \pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
          \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
          \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{0pt}}
}}

\tikzset{dim/.style args={#1,#2}{decoration={add dim,distance=#2},
                decorate,
                postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,
                                                 raise=#2,
                                                 text align={align=center},
                                                 text={#1}}}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,2);
\coordinate (C) at (8,-2);

\draw[dim={5 cm,10pt,}]  (A) --  (B);
\draw[dim={7 cm,-15pt}]  (B) --  (C); 

\draw[fill=gray] (A) circle(2pt); 
\draw[fill=gray] (B) circle(2pt);
\draw[fill=gray] (C) circle(2pt);   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Update : possible with `edge`

```
\draw (A) edge [dim={5 cm,10pt}]  (B) 
          edge[dim={7 cm,-15pt}]  (C)
       (B)edge[dim={4 cm,+10pt}]  (C);
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Is it possible to adjust this such that one can write something like `\draw (A) dim[text,above] (B) -- (C) -- (D) dim[text] (E) dim[text,below] (F) -- circle;`

Comment: @user4011 No it's impossible  because decoration is applied to the whole path; you can use `edge` like  in my update code.

Comment: Alain, thanks for this great answer. However, I cannot label the dimension line with a mathematical symbol. As soon as type in `$a$` for exmaple, the macro does weird stuff. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I'm using pdflatex and had to terminate the application manually after passing a math symbol to the macro as a label...

Comment: @AlainMatthes can you fix some problem in your sty. Here is the link in my question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381401/change-the-distance-dimension-of-a-line-as-a-decoration-in-tikz

Comment: @AlainMatthes Is it possible to draw a dotted line between the two lines marking the ends of the segment?

Comment: @LeQuanPlus What do you mean by sty?

Comment: @AndréC yes it's possible ! You need to use ` \pgfsetdash`

Comment: @AlainMatthes Can you elaborate?

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 15):

Here is a solution, via `to path`, that allows to use the second required syntax:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  dim above/.style={to path={\pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \draw[>=latex,|<->|] let
        \p1=($(\tikztostart)!2mm!90:(\tikztotarget)$),
        \p2=($(\tikztotarget)!2mm!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
        in(\p1) -- (\p2) node[pos=.5,sloped,above]{#1};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }(\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    }
  },
  dim below/.style={to path={\pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \draw[>=latex,|<->|] let 
        \p1=($(\tikztostart)!2mm!90:(\tikztotarget)$),
        \p2=($(\tikztotarget)!2mm!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
        in (\p1) -- (\p2) node[pos=.5,sloped,below]{#1};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }(\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) to[dim above=text] (4,-2) to[dim below=other text](0,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Improved version by removing `(\tikztostart)`

To get a *continuous* path (to fill it for example), you can use:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  dim above/.style={to path={\pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \draw[line width=.4pt,>=latex,|<->|] let 
        \p1=($(\tikztostart)!2mm!90:(\tikztotarget)$),
        \p2=($(\tikztotarget)!2mm!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
        in (\p1) -- (\p2) node[text=,pos=.5,sloped,above]{#1};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      } -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    }
  },
  dim below/.style={to path={\pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \draw[line width=.4pt,>=latex,|<->|] let 
        \p1=($(\tikztostart)!2mm!90:(\tikztotarget)$),
        \p2=($(\tikztotarget)!2mm!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
        in (\p1) -- (\p2) node[text=,pos=.5,sloped,below]{#1};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      } -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw=blue,text=red,line width=1pt,fill=orange!50,line cap=round,line join=round]
  (0,0)
  to[dim above=first text] (4,-1) node[right] {A}
  to[dim below=second text](-3,-4) node[below left] {B}
  to[dim above=third text] (0,0) node[above=1mm]{C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108408/discussion-between-paul-gaborit-and-schrodingers-cat).

Answer (score 10):

In the interim, for whomever might be interested in a [`pstricks`](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) version of this style, which presents a pretty straight-forward way of rotating text labels between paths:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add}% http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,5)
  \pcline{-}(0,0)(3,2)
  \pcline[offset=12pt]{|-|}(0,0)(3,2)
  \ncput*[nrot=:U]{Length}

  \pcline{-}(5,1)(8,0)
  \pcline[offset=-12pt]{|<->|}(5,1)(8,0)
  \nbput[nrot=:U]{Text}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It requires the traditional `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf` or `xelatex` compiling sequence (unless you're using [`auto-pst-pdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf)).

Comment: `|<*->|*` and `|*-|*` give more precise ends.