# How to draw "section-size" arrows using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I searched for problems like this, but couldn't find any approach. Then, I don't believe this is a duplicated question.

The question is: how to draw section-size arrow marks (like the one shown in the picture) using tikz.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what does section-sized mean? Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (tmp) {$\phi$};
\draw (tmp.north east) -- ++ (-3,0);
\draw (tmp.south east) -- ++ (-3,0);
\draw[<-] (tmp.north) -- ++ (0,0.5);
\draw[<-] (tmp.south) -- ++ (0,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi @marmot. I mean that I would like to draw those couple of arrows that point to each other indicating the size of a section (because is generally used to point diameter of pipes, etc). I know how to draw them separately... but is there a way to draw at once using a simple code?

Comment: I guess I got most confused by the fact that section has several meanings. So you are talking about diameters, and not the things that come with the `\section` command, right?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I mean @marmot :)

Comment: How about [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37926/121799)?

Comment: It is different from what I asked @marmot. I asked for arrows that are disconnected and point into one another. They have the same size and delimit a space corresponding to the size I want to explict with a value like $\phi$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`tikz-dimline`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-dimline) was designed for this pourpose. Following code is an example from its documentation.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw[help lines] (-1,-1) grid (4,7);
\draw (0,0) -- (0,4) -- (.5,4) -- (.5,5) -- (1.,5) -- (1.,4) -- (1.5,4) -- (1.5,0)
-- cycle;
\dimline[color=blue,
extension start length=-0.25, extension end length=-0.25]{(2.75,0)}{(2.75,4)}{4.0};
\dimline[color=red,
line style={arrows=dimline reverse-dimline reverse},
label style={above=0.8ex,font=\tiny},
extension start length=1,
extension end length=1]{(0.5,5.6)}{(1.0,5.6)}{0.5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

An other approach using  the *To path operation* :

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\tikzset{
        diameter/.style={to path={},
                        execute at end to={
                        \draw[Stealth-](\tikztostart)--($(\tikztostart)!-0.5cm!(\tikztotarget)$);
                        \draw[Stealth-](\tikztotarget)--($(\tikztotarget)!-0.5cm!(\tikztostart)$);
                        \path (\tikztostart)--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes;
                        },
        }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw(0,0)--(2,0);
        \draw(0,1)--(2,1);
        \path[diameter] (0.5,0)to node{\(\phi\)}(1,1);

        \path[diameter] (1.5,0)to node{\(\phi\)}(1.5,1);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]